# C++ regex failure (gcc vs microsoft compiler)

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following regex code in a project:

```
// Defintions to make readability easier:
#define BEGIN "\\{"
#define END "\\}\n"
#define VEC2 "\\((.+), (.+)\\)"
#define VEC3 "\\((.+), (.+), (.+)\\)"
#define COMMA ", "
....
char input[256];
fgets(buffer, 256, file);
....
std::cmatch result;
std::regex_match(input, result, std::regex("vertex " BEGIN VEC3 COMMA VEC3 COMMA VEC2 END)); // fails
```

Here is an example input:

```
vertex {(0.000002, 0.445344, 0.996317), (0.000000, 0.979064, -0.203466), (0.507950, 0.502418)}
```

Essientially, this regex expression fails (returns false) on GCC v5.4, but it worked flawlessly on Microsoft Window's official compiler, and it also worked on many regex test sites. I believe this should work, but wonder why it fails.

Comment: Describe "does not work at all"

Comment: Works well on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bsBH6AzbHtkqXSbe).

Comment: I just tried making a constant string my code... and it worked. This means it probably has something to do with the line endings :(

Comment: Thanks a bunch @xskxzr! You helped me figure this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, turns out it was my line endings. The file was written out by a windows program, so the line ended with `\r\n`. For future regex'ers, check your line endings ;)

Comment: Why are you using `fgets` in C++? I don't know a lot about C I/O, but if you open a text file with `fstream`, it should convert line endings for you.

Comment: Very nice suggestion @FeiXiang :) I will look into those